# Update in MySql DB

Tags: mysql, asp.net, typescript, razor

I have to save the user permissions when the admin, in the user management page, choose what every user can (or can't) see.
After doing the cshtml page to show all the available pages, I have to save the changes through a typescript page:

```
Core.compatibility.ready(() => {
let editGestioneUtenti = document.getElementById("edit-gestioneRuoli");

if (editGestioneUtenti)        
    editGestioneUtenti.addEventListener("click", async ev => {
        let id = Route.get("gestioneRuoli");
        await edit(gestioneutenti, "/api/GestionePermessi/gestioneruoli/{Id}", id);
    });

let salvaPermessi = document.getElementById("btn-save-permessi");
if (salvaPermessi)
    salvaPermessi.addEventListener("click", async ev => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        let menu = [];
        let tab = [];
        let func = [];

        const data = {
            _id: val,
            _menu: idmenu,
            _tab: idtab,
            _func: idfunc
        };

        var val = $("#Username").val();
        $(".combomenu").each(function () {

            menu.push($(this).val());
        })
        var idmenu = $("#menu").val();
        $(".combomenu").each(function () {

            menu.push($(this).val());
        })
        var idtab = $("#tab").val();
        $(".combotab").each(function () {

            tab.push($(this).val());
        })
        var idfunc = $("#func").val();
        $(".combofunc").each(function () {

            func.push($(this).val());
        })
    })
    
        try {
            await Core.compatibility.fetch("/api/gestionepermessi/gestioneruoli/", {

                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            }).then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText)
                } else {
                    $(".combomenu").each(function () {

                        jQuery.each(_menu, function (i, val) {
                            $("#" + val).remove();
                        })
                    })
                }
            }).then(response => {
                    $(".combotab").each(function () {

                        jQuery.each(_tab, function (i, val) {
                            $("#" + val).remove();
                        })
                    })                    
            }).then(resp => {
                    $(".combofunc").each(function () {

                        jQuery.each(_func, function (i, val) {
                            $("#" + val).remove();
                        })
                    });
                })                
        } catch (e) {
            SwalWrapper.fire({
                type: "error",
                title: "Errore",
                text: e
            });
        };
    });
```

This part of code contains some errors, indeed the compiler show me this messages:

```
cannot find name 'data'
cannot find name '_menu'
cannot find name '_tab'
cannot find name '_func'
```

but I've declared at line 18 of the code I've posted. How can I fix it?